# Cast DiskFileitem to Formfile item

Tags: java, file, upload, struts

How to cast or convert org apache diskfileitem to apache struts upload formfile.i am getting diskileobject and want struts formfile frim it

Comment: Please post some code that you wrote and what specific issue you are facing in achieving your desired results

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `DiskFileItem` **fully qualified class name** is `org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem`.

Secondly, your question is unclear. If you want to use `Struts` to do file upload, use the Struts `<html:file>` tag and in your `Action`, have a property of type `FormFile`. Obviously Struts uses Apache Commons FileUpload in order for File upload to work so there's no need for you to do some workaround.